# THREE.JS Cannot read property 'matrixWorld' of undefined

Tags: three.js, 3d

When I create a sprite, OrbitControls works perfectly.
But when I switch to FirstPersonControls, everything freezes and the console gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matrixWorld' of undefined
    at Sprite.raycast (three.js:26051)
    at intersectObject (three.js:44583)
    at Raycaster.intersectObjects (three.js:44658)
    at animate (mainview.php?project_id=46&tipo=1:936)
```

Raycasting code:

```
   if (firstorbit) {

           if (l % 5 == 0) {
               var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);

               vector = camera.localToWorld(vector);
               vector.sub(camera.position);

               var raycasterGround = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector);

               var intersectsGround = raycasterGround.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);


               if (intersectsGround.length > 0) {          

                   if (intersectsGround[0].distance < 1.21) {

                       camera.position.y = (camera.position.y + (1.21 - intersectsGround[0].distance));

                   }


                   if (intersectsGround[0].distance > 1.36 && intersectsGround[0].distance < 1.45) {

                       camera.position.y = (camera.position.y - (intersectsGround[0].distance - 1.215));


                   }

               }


           }
           if (l % 3 == 0) {

               var vector1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);

               vector1 = camera.localToWorld(vector1);
               vector1.sub(camera.position);

               var raycasterFront = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector1);

               var intersectsFront = raycasterFront.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);


               if (intersectsFront.length > 0) {


                   if (intersectsFront[0].distance < 0.3) {
                       controls.moveForward = false;
                       controls.w = false;
                   } else {
                       controls.w = true;
                   }                  

               } else controls.w = true;
           }
       }
```

Raycasting code that I use on mouse click to measure something:

```
function getIntersections( event ) {
  var vectorMouse = new THREE.Vector2();

  vectorMouse.set(
   mouse.x,
    mouse.y );

  var raycasterClick = new THREE.Raycaster();
  raycasterClick.setFromCamera( vectorMouse, camera );

var intersectsClick = raycasterClick.intersectObjects( scene.children,true );


  return intersectsClick;

}
```

I am not sure if the problem is with the sprite or with my raycasting code. But when I remove the sprite, everything works perfectly. And when I remove the Raycasting code, everything also works perfectly.

Comment: Um, the error does not seem related to `FirstPersonControls`. Can you please share your raycasting-related code.

Comment: If I remove the raycaster(s) or the sprite, everything works fine. The problem is into the sprite raycasting.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? I think this runtime error needs requires debugging...

Comment: Just a note: Don't bother creating a new `Raycaster` every time you need one. Just create one, and use `setFromCamera` (like you're doing already) to update it for the current casting.

Comment: In your console, where you see the error, click on "three.js:26051". It should take you to the line where the error is occurring. Please copy that line and include it in your question. Otherwise, we will need to see a live example, like Mugen87 requested.

Comment: three.js:26051 "viewWorldMatrix.copy( raycaster._camera.matrixWorld );"